# 'virtualenv' is not recognized after pip install

Tags: python, virtualenv

CMD does not recognize the `virtualenv` command after `pip install`, as shown below:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22509.1000]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\System32>cd C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\GFG

C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\GFG>pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (20.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.2 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\adity\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.4.1)

C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\GFG>virtualenv venv
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Desktop\GFG>
```

Comment: Run--> pip uninstall virtualenv    ,and then--> pip install virtualenv

Comment: try using it as python module: `python -m virtualenv`

Answer (score 3):

1. If Scripts is already in path variable then check if you have virtualenv.exe in that folder is it is not thee then remove virtualenv and add it again. Just like @saeed-emamyari suggested.

```
pip uninstall virtualenv 
pip install virtualenv
```

2. virtualenv.exe is in pyhton scripts folder and this folder must be in your PATH environment variable. Add the python script folder path to your path variable. Location should be `C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`. You need to open a new cmd to test because environment variable do not get reload after cmd is opened. (No idea why microsoft won't just make an event listener/handler for this)